# Slider value doesn't update the value unless it's moved

Tags: swift

I've been playing around with a basic betting app and I can't seem to figure out this problem.

The slider is a percentage of the `bank` unless it's moved at which point it will update the value based on the value. If it isn't moved and kept at the previous value it also uses the previous value.

For example:

My bank is 1000. I move the slider to 10% to bet 100. I win and now my bank is 1100.

I want to bet 10% again but it doesn't update to the new value which should be 110. It will keep the same value of 100 until the slider is moved? How can I fix it so that even if it doesn't move the value of 10% of the bank is true.

```
 @IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider)

    {
        betAmount.text = String(format: "%.0f%%",sender.value)
        wager = Int(sender.value) * bank / 100
    }

 @IBAction func flipCoin(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        let number = [1,2]
        winnings = wager + ((wager * 90) / 100)


        if let coin = coins.randomElement()
        {
            if(coin == 1 && wager <= bank && wager > 0)
            {

                youBet.text = ("$\(wager)")
                bank += winnings
                bankLabel.text = ("$\(bank)")

            }
            else if(coin == 2 && wager <= bank && wager > 0)
            {

                youBet.text = ("$\(wager)")
                bank -= wager
                bankLabel.text = ("$\(bank)")

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: In the code you've shown, you don't have anything that updates the value of `wager` except in `slider(_ sender: UISlider)` which will only be called when the slider is moved. You should recalculate the wager again after each coin flip and  the value of `bank` has increased/decreased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to do the following:-

1. If you don't already have an `IBOutlet` for the UISlider, create one (e.g. called `sliderOutlet`.
2. Extract the contents of the `slider` func to a new private function, called (e.g.) `updateWager()`. Reference `sliderOutlet` instead of `sender`.
3. Change the `slider` func to call your new function.
4. Also call this function from the end of `flipCoin` (i.e. after the bank has been updated).

This will make the wager calculation occur automatically when the flip is complete. You can also call the new function should any other event (now or in the future) update the bank.

I.e.:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sliderOutlet: UISlider! // Create this from the storyboard
func updateWager()
{
    betAmount.text = String(format: "%.0f%%", sliderOutlet.value)
    wager = Int(sliderOutlet.value) * bank / 100.0
}

@IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider)
{
  updateWager()
}

@IBAction func flipCoin(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let number = [1,2]
    winnings = wager + ((wager * 90) / 100)


    if let coin = coins.randomElement()
    {
        if(coin == 1 && wager <= bank && wager > 0)
        {

            youBet.text = ("$\(wager)")
            bank += winnings
            bankLabel.text = ("$\(bank)")

        }
        else if(coin == 2 && wager <= bank && wager > 0)
        {

            youBet.text = ("$\(wager)")
            bank -= wager
            bankLabel.text = ("$\(bank)")

        }
        updateWager()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. Is `sliderOutlet` also made from the slider? So the slider is both seperately an outlet and an action?

Comment: Spot on. Ctrl-Drag from the slider to your ViewController class in the assistant editor, then choose Outlet (I assume you've done this before).

Comment: Perfect! It works!! Thank you, I've been stuck on that for the last two days.